# Issue with initialising form element through a button element

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to initialise a form element once a button is pressed. What I have attempted is to use bootstrap data-target (on line 10) attribute to call the form id "#hiddenUploadField" (line 27). Currently it doesn't do anything. Any tips would be helpful here.

I've inserted below the code:

```
  <!-- End of navbar -->
  <div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row fill">
      <div class="col-sm-4 fill">
        <div class="panel panel-default fill">
          <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="tooltip">
            Files &amp; Designs
            <!-- <span id="refreshBuckets" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="cursor: pointer"></span> -->
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" style="float: right" id="uploadFile" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data"
              data-target="#hiddenUploadField">
              
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Upload design
            </button>
            
          </div>
          <div id="appBuckets">
            Your designs should be here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 fill">
        <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form id="uploadFile" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="hiddenUploadField" type="file" name="theFile" style="visibility:hidden" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an onclick attribute to call on the function solved it. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
 <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" style="float: right" id="uploadFile" onclick="uploadFile()" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data"
              data-target="#hiddenUploadField">
              
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span> Upload design
            </button>
```